# How to automatically remove child entities?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'd like to remove entities from my table and have it auto-removed any entities that are childs of it.

Example:

```
class User {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval=true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    List<Address> addresses;
}
```

When I remove a User that has no address, everything works fine. Also removing an address without removing the user works.

But: If I try to remove a user that has still some addresses, I'm getting `org.hsqldb.HsqlException`:

```
integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FK_ADDRESS_USER_ID table: ADDRESS
```

What might be wrong here?
Or is this not supported and I have to explicitly remove all contained `Address` objects first before deleting a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a problem with a foreign key constraint. Use a DB tool like Aqua Data Studio or similar (you can probably also do this in your IDE, in Eclipse - Data Source Explorer view), to show the create script for your ADDRESS table. It should contain something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TESTSCHEMA.ADDRESS
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK1ED033D4E91AAFD9
    FOREIGN KEY(FK_ADDRESS_USER_ID)
    REFERENCES TESTSCHEMA.USER(ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The point being the `ON DELETE CASCADE` part in your case. If this is missing or is different, that probably is what is causing the problem. If the table is auto-generated by Hibernate, this constraint should be valid, but keep in mind that there are differences between databases. It could be that the table was generated before the Hibernate's @OnDelete annotation was added, so now you are getting the "foreign key no action" integrity constraint violation.

Not related to the issue, but do note that `orphanRemoval=true` will try to remove the address from the **database**, when it is removed from the collection in the User entity.

Also, check [this](http://eddii.wordpress.com/2006/11/16/hibernate-on-deletecascade-performance/) out for details on Hibernate’s support for database ON DELETE CASCADE constraint.

Comment: Is generating the appropriate constraints really how Hibernate achieves cascading? I'd have expected it to just delete the child entities automatically when `orphanRemoval` is true.

Comment: Cascading can be done by Hibernate (JPA) if it is so set with `cascade` in the mapping annotation, but if you use @OnDelete, Hibernate will set the constraint when table is created, and the cascade will be done on the database level (SQL cascade delete), instead of the regular Hibernate mechanism. This has the function of reducing the number of SQL statements issued by Hibernate. As for the `orphanRemoval`, it is used to mark the entity for deletion when it is "removed from a @OneToMany collection or an associated entity is dereferenced from a @OneToOne association", as specified in spec.